# How to handle parent child records in Google big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have below set of data ([Data for conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLQSQ.png))

```
| ITEM | PARENT_ITEM |
| -----| ------------|
| AA   | AB          |
| AB   | AC          |
| AC   | AD          |
| BA   | BB          |
| BB   | BC          |
| FG   | GG          |
```

I want to transform above set of data to below set

```
| ITEM | PARENT_ITEM    | FINAL_PARENT |  
| -----| -------------- | -------------| 
| AA   | AB             | AD           | 
| AB   | AC             | AD           | 
| AC   | AD             | AD           | 
| BA   | BB             | BC           | 
| BB   | BC             | BC           | 
| FG   | GG             | GG           |
```

I found out that Big query doesn't support recursive sql. I wrote Stored Procedure but I cant call SP within standard SQL. Can someone help?

There could any level of depth in hierarchy and i dont want to hard code the depth.

Abhijeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery Team just introduced [Recursive CTE!](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#February_02_2022) Hooray!!

With recursive cte you can use below approach

```
with recursive iterations as (
  select *, parent_item as final_parent from your_table 
  where not parent_item in (
    select item from your_table
  )
  union all 
  select b.*, a.final_parent
  from iterations a join your_table b
  on a.item = b.parent_item
)
select *
from iterations
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

If you want to test it with dummy data  - use below example

```
with recursive your_table AS ( 
  select 'AA' as ITEM, 'AB' as PARENT_ITEM union all 
  select 'AB' as ITEM, 'AC' as PARENT_ITEM union all 
  select 'AC' as ITEM, 'AD' as PARENT_ITEM union all 
  select 'BA' as ITEM, 'BB' as PARENT_ITEM union all 
  select 'BB' as ITEM, 'BC' as PARENT_ITEM 
),iterations as (
  select *, parent_item as final_parent from your_table 
  where not parent_item in (
    select item from your_table
  )
  union all 
  select b.*, a.final_parent
  from iterations a join your_table b
  on a.item = b.parent_item
)
select *
from iterations
```

Comment: WITH your_table AS (     select 'AA' as ITEM, 'AB' as PARENT_ITEM  union all
   select 'AB' as ITEM, 'AC' as PARENT_ITEM  union all
   select 'AC' as ITEM, 'AD' as PARENT_ITEM  union all
   select 'BA' as ITEM, 'BB' as PARENT_ITEM  union all
   select 'BB' as ITEM, 'BC' as PARENT_ITEM  )
, recursive iterations as (
  select *, parent_item as final_parent from your_table 
  where not parent_item in ( select item from your_table  )
  union all 
  select b.*, a.final_parent
  from iterations a join your_table b
  on a.item = b.parent_item
)
select *
from iterations

Comment: I tried running above query but is giving me syntax error. I see "Recursive CTE" still in preview mode. Do i need to enable it before i can use it?

Comment: you use wrong syntax when added cte with dummy data - see update in answer  - I added example of how to properly do so!